# Service running over network : Windows cannot access the file for one of the following reasons...appears once per day, How to troubleshoot?

Tags: windows-server-2012, filesystems, windows-service

Our prod. setup is one web server, one sql server and one application server. On application server we have services installed which located one the sql server.
We never had problems accessing the files, but since we recently switched to a new vdc we get this error once per day for any of the services :

```
Windows cannot access the file  for one of the following reasons: there is a 
problem with the network connection, the disk that the file is stored on, 
or the storage drivers installed on this computer; or the disk is missing. 
Windows closed the program.
```

Our hosting partner says it's because the sql server is sometimes on 100% cpu and that's why the service can't be accessed by another machine. I personally disagree with this, but I can't prove the opposite.

The service of course has a recovery rule set, so it restarts after that, but still I would like to avoud that. How can i troubleshoot that?

Comment: can you comment when you downvote? I would like to improve the question.